# Using lookups to match multiple values in columns in Power BI/DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table of university unit data. The units have historically been delivered in two different lengths (under the same unit code): sessions and terms. It looks something like this:

| UnitCode | Year | OfferedIn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UNIT001 | 2021 | Session1 |
| UNIT001 | 2021 | Session2 |
| UNIT002 | 2021 | Session1 |
| UNIT002 | 2021 | Term4 |
| UNIT003 | 2020 | Session1 |
| UNIT003 | 2020 | Session3 |
| UNIT003 | 2021 | Term2 |

I need to slice various graphs by units that were offered in both styles, regardless of which actual year, session, or term. So the extra column would be as on the right below:

| UnitCode | Year | OfferedIn | OfferedInBoth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UNIT001 | 2021 | Session1 |  |
| UNIT001 | 2021 | Session2 |  |
| UNIT002 | 2021 | Session1 | TRUE |
| UNIT002 | 2021 | Term4 | TRUE |
| UNIT003 | 2020 | Session1 | TRUE |
| UNIT003 | 2020 | Session3 | TRUE |
| UNIT003 | 2021 | Term2 | TRUE |

So I want to look at a value in the UnitCode column and see if it has both different kinds of values in the OfferedIn column (I can do 'contains' expressions for the types) in any row where the unit code is the same. How do I generate the OfferedInBoth column? (Or do I need to create a new table? I'd prefer to keep it as dynamic as possible, as the dataset will add new unit codes over time.)

Comment: You say you want to add an extra column, rather than use a measure. I take it then that you do not require the new calculation to respond to any filtering you make on your table? For example, if you were to filter Year for 2020, would you still expect to see a result of TRUE for UNIT003?

Comment: I want to be able to filter on the results, but not to have the results affected by any filters such as you describe (if a unit has ever been in this group, I want to include it, regardless of whether the years I'm currently looking at contain one or the other or both of the qualifying conditions), so yes, I think your assumption is correct, and a column seems to suit my requirements better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a **calculated column** using the DAX code below. Replace "Table1" references with the name of your table and add any session/term values applicable to the SWITCH statements.

```
OfferedInBoth = 
VAR unitCode = Table1[UnitCode]
VAR unitCodeTable = FILTER(Table1, Table1[UnitCode] = unitCode)

VAR containsSession = 
    SWITCH(
        TRUE, 
        CONTAINS(unitCodeTable, Table1[OfferedIn], "Session1"), TRUE(), 
        CONTAINS(unitCodeTable, Table1[OfferedIn], "Session2"), TRUE(), 
        CONTAINS(unitCodeTable, Table1[OfferedIn], "Session3"), TRUE(), 
        CONTAINS(unitCodeTable, Table1[OfferedIn], "Session4"), TRUE(), 
        FALSE
    )

VAR containsTerm = 
    SWITCH(
        TRUE, 
        CONTAINS(unitCodeTable, Table1[OfferedIn], "Term1"), TRUE(), 
        CONTAINS(unitCodeTable, Table1[OfferedIn], "Term2"), TRUE(), 
        CONTAINS(unitCodeTable, Table1[OfferedIn], "Term3"), TRUE(), 
        CONTAINS(unitCodeTable, Table1[OfferedIn], "Term4"), TRUE(), 
        FALSE
    )

RETURN containsSession && containsTerm
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a **measure** as below-

```
true_false = 

var current_row_unitcode = min('your_table_name'[UnitCode])

var count_sess = 
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        ALL('your_table_name'),
        'your_table_name'[UnitCode] = current_row_unitcode
        && LEFT('your_table_name'[OfferedIn],4) = "Sess"
    )
)

var count_term = 
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        ALL('your_table_name'),
        'your_table_name'[UnitCode] = current_row_unitcode
        && LEFT('your_table_name'[OfferedIn],4) = "Term"
    )
)

return if(
    count_sess >=1 && count_term >= 1, "True",""
)
```

Output-

**[image: strong text]**